# Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,Height,Size error

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to create a c# console application that takes a screenshot of the entire screen, i know this has been asked a bunch of times on SO, but i have a problem with it that i just can't find an answer to.

This is my code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
{
 g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
 bmp.Save("screenshot.png");  // saves the image
}
```

But for some reason I get an error that says

> The name 'Screen' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Okay @Josh, do is there anything i can do to take a screenshot from a console application that you know of?

Comment: @RufusL I already tested that out and it doesn't work.

Comment: @RufusL I tried WriteLine on `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width` and it only writes `X`, when I try to assign the Width to an int it just crashes and stops execution

Comment: @Josh Weird. I just copy/pasted the code above, added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, and when I ran it, it took a screenshot and saved it as `"screenshot.png"`.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Well if it works for you, I'll delete my comment since it seems to be an issue on my end

Answer (score 2):

> But for some reason i get an error that says, *"The name 'Screen' does not exist in the current context"*

The reason for this is that the `Screen` class belongs to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly, which is not referenced by default in a Console Application.

To resolve this issue, add a reference to the assembly in your project and then add `using System.Windows.Forms` to the top of your code file.

To add a reference:

1. Right-click on your project in the solution Explorer and choose "Add Reference..."
2. In the Reference Manager window that opens, navigate to `Assemblies -> Framework` on the left
3. Scroll down the middle window and check the box next to `System.Windows.Forms`
4. Click "OK"

Then add a `using` statement to your code file, similar to this sample based on your code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(string filePath = null)
        {
            var bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            var bmp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bounds.Size);
            }

            if (filePath != null) bmp.Save(filePath);

            return bmp;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taking a screenshot now...");

            TakeScreenshot("screenshot.bmp");

            Console.WriteLine("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Side note:** Many users have more than one monitor these days, so if you want to take a screenshot that captures *all* the screens, you can create a rectangle that encompasses all screens:

```
public static Bitmap TakeScreenshot(string filePath = null)
{
    var rect = new Rectangle();

    // Take a screenshot that includes all screens by
    // creating a rectangle that captures all monitors
    foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        var bounds = screen.Bounds;
        var width = bounds.X + bounds.Width;
        var height = bounds.Y + bounds.Height;

        if (width > rect.Width) rect.Width = width;
        if (height > rect.Height) rect.Height = height;
    }

    var bmp = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);

    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, rect.Size);
    }

    if (filePath != null) bmp.Save(filePath);

    return bmp;
}
```